# Need good material on SWT layouts

Tags: eclipse-rcp, swt

I am learning SWT and I am in need of some good material on SWT layouts. Anyone have some good material or links for SWT layouts? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn SWT and its layouts is trying things out yourself.
But I recommend the following ressources for a start:

- The noteworthy SWT tutorial on [Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswttutorial/)
- Furthermore the eclipse / JFace / SWT section on [java2s](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CatalogSWT-JFace-Eclipse.htm)
- Last but not least the official SWT homepage with its [examples](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) and if you like its [widget page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) with links to javadoc and code snippets

Answer (score 3):

[The Definitive Guide to SWT and Jface](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=978-1590598665&x=0&y=0) by Robert Harris is pretty good and explains all of the basic layout in a useful ways with lots and lots of examples.

Using [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) can also help a lot, as you here see - in real-time - the consequences of your UI decisions...

The absolutely best it to try and try again...

Comment: +1 for using WindowBuilder. GridLayout and FormLayout definitely require some practice, and WindowBuilder speeds up that cycle enormously.

Answer (score 3):

There is really no reason not to use MigLayout. It's the best layout manager for "hand-made" GUI. Very powerful, easy to understand and use.. There is version for Swing and SWT as well..
[MigLayout website](http://www.miglayout.com)

Comment: I am slightly worried as the license is GPL. I will be using it for a proprietary application and LGPL would have been good for me.

Comment: It's dual licence, so you can use GPL or BSD depending on your needs.

_It is licensed under the very free BSD or GPL license, whichever you prefer._